# NPSP 3.0 Issue with data import.

Tags: npsp

I am trying to import contacts into NPSP thru NPSP data import object.
It’s working fine with contacts without account information. It's importing contacts with household account.

Issue is household account also creating even for the contacts with account information. 
I can find the contact in related lists of both household account (under contacts) and specified account (under Affiliated Contacts).

Can we avoid creating household account for those contacts which are having account information.
Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The NPSP Data Import utility (which uses a different process than a standard direct-to-object import and is only included in NPSP 3) follows the best practice model of NPSP 3 where Contacts are connected to Household Accounts as their account, and Organizations (Accounts) are their Primary Affiliation (custom field). The NPSP Data Import does not allow for more standard Salesforce Contact/Account relationships, although you could of course use other tools for that import.

More detail can be found in the [NPSP Data Import workbook](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Administrators-Guide-to-Importing-Donor-Data).

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the template with the NPSP data translation object when you imported your data into NPSP 3? There should be places for importing the account as well as the primary contact (contact1) and a 2nd contact (contact2) if they exist and you want to import them into the same household. Once in the object, you need to do an upsert if the account already exists. You may also want to try using Apsona which is a freebie for non-profits that many find easy to use for bringing in data for updates like this.